# Existence of a one-to-one function (injection) from one finite set to another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Consider two finite sets, $A$ and $B$.

Is it fine to say that “an injection $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ exists *if and only if* $|A| \leq |B|$”? If it is, could you please suggest as to how I might explain the idea? If it is not, could you please say why not?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define what is $|A|$ (i.e. the number of elements of a finite set).

A way to define $|A|$ is by means of cardinality. One says that $|A|=n$ if there exists a bijection between $A$ and $I_n = \{1,2,...,n\}$.
Using this definition it is very easy to show that if $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$ and $n\le m$ then there is an injection between $A$ and $B$. Let $\phi \colon I_n \to A$ and $\psi \colon I_m \to B$ be bijections. Then when $n\le m$ the composition $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}\colon A \to B$ is well defined and is injective. Conversely if $f\colon A \to B$ is injective, then the map $\psi^{-1} \circ f\circ \phi\colon I_n \to I_m$ is also injective, hence $n\le m$.

This definition (using cardinality) is also very natural. You say that $|A|=n$ if you can enumerate the elements of $A$ by counting from 1 to $n$. So the previous proof is actually also an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

To show that such a function exists: Number the elements of each set. Now use the numbering to construct a function.

To show that a function does not exist: Use the pigeonhole principle, where the pigeons are elements of $A$ and the pigeonholes elements of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed. For finite $A, B$, an injection exists if and only if $|A|\leq |B|$.

To justify this, consider $\implies$. If $|A| = m \leq |B| = n$, then we can index the elements of each, and for each element $a_i \in A$, $1\leq i \leq m$, and define a function that maps $a_i \mapsto b_i$.

To prove the other direction, prove the following contrapositive: If $|A| \gt |B|$, then ***no*** injective function $f: A\to B$ can exist.  Use the pigeon-hole principle to show that if $|A| = m >|B| = n$, then any mapping $A \to B$ will necessarily have to map two or more elements of $A$ to $B$, since there are more elements in $A$ than in $B$, and hence, injectivity fails.